# Cleanup field value via soap direct web services

Tags: servicenow

I would like to remove assignment_group per soap request by setting empty  tag.
As expected this will be ignored by the servicenow application.

What would be the right way to remove values from the fields?
unfortunately i could not find any related documentation.

Hier is my request snippet.

```html
POST /incident.do?SOAP&amp;displayvalue=true HTTP/1.1
Host: dev123.service-now.com
Authorization: Basic
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Basic <AuthorisationCode>
Cache-Control: no-cache

<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inc="http://www.service-now.com/incident">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <inc:update>
            <sys_id>85071a1347c12200e0ef563dbb9a71c1</sys_id>
            <assignment_group></assignment_group>
        </inc:update>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use a direct SOAP call to clear out a field, but you should be able to create a *Transform map* that coalesces on the `sys_id` to handle this.

Something along these lines

```
if (source.assignment_group.nil()) {
    target.assignment_group = '';
}
```

I haven't tried it, but you might be able to set the **Copy empty fields** to `true` on the *Transform map* and have it work without a script.

Comment: thank you, i know how to do it via transform map. BUT the use case is, as described, "direct web service"